# Password Hashing PHP 7

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash

I am currently learning PHP and I have been looking through the forum for current thinking on how best to Hash passwords in PHP.

Can anyone advise on what is currently the best password hashing method to use.  I have been told about PHPass, but are there better alternatives in 2017?

Thank you for any advice,

Ian

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should never encrypt passwords, you should only hash them. Encryption implies that you can decrypt the password into a human readable form. You should never do that. Hashing is a one way street and once hashed a password cannot be recovered in human readable form.

Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying terminology, I have some code that encrypts a password and I was not comfortable that the passwords could be decrypted also.

Comment: Exactly websites should never actually store your password but a hash of it. This way if your database has been comprised well at least you didn't give out thousands of user passwords.