# How do I hash a password that goes into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, insert, passwords

```
$useremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['useremail']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['password']);
$confirm_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['confirm_password']);
$f_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['f_name']);
$l_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['l_name']);
$grade_level = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['grade_level']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (useremail, password, f_name, l_name, grade_level) VALUES ('$useremail', '$password', '$f_name', '$l_name', '$grade_level')";

if ($_POST["password"] === $_POST["confirm_password"])......
```

I've tried to change the code to include the HASH_PASSWORD but I don't believe I am doing it right.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 2):

First at all: Please try to use `PDO` in addition to prepared statements. It is newer and safer.
For hashing a string you can use following code:

```
$hashpassword = password_hash($yourpassword, PASSWORD_DEAULT);
```

For checking if an input is the same as the hash you can use:

```
password_verify($yourinput, $dbpassword);
```

This returns a boolean: So `true` or `false`

Comment: PDO is not safer (nor is it any less safe). Prepared statements are safer, and you can use them with mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Please use PHP's built-in functions password_hash() and password_verify()to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() compatibility pack. Make sure you don't escape passwords or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

(Taken from [Password Hashing PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120586/password-hashing-php-7))

<strike>Also might I recommend "preparing your statements" using a PDO</strike>

Edit: After further reading, I agree with Red Herring... I retract my recommendation

Comment: Why not just prepare his statements using mysqli?